# macro - open all files in a folder

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I want to open all files in a specified folder and have the following code

```
Sub OpenFiles()
Dim MyFolder As String
Dim MyFile As String
MyFolder = "\\ILAFILESERVER\Public\Documents\Renewable Energy\FiTs\1 Planning
           Department\Marks Tracker\Quality Control Reports"
MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\*.xlsx")
Do While MyFile <> ""
Workbooks.Open Filename:=MyFolder & "\" & MyFile
Loop
End Sub
```

The problem I have is that it just keeps trying to open the first file in the folder repeatedly and won't move on. Can anybody help, I'm a bit of a novice at VBA and could really do with some assistance. I'm trying to open around 30 reports that are all in .xlsx format. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to open all of the files in a folder at the same time?

Answer (score 34):

You have to add this line just before `loop`

```
    MyFile = Dir
Loop
```

Comment: Hi, Ross and welcome to StackOverflow! Here, it's customary to thank people by clicking the 'accept as answer' button next to their answer. It's shaped like a big checkmark. This way your helper gets points as a reward for helping you and you get credit for contributing a helpful Q&A page.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Len(StrFile) > 0` in loop check statement !

```
Sub openMyfile()

    Dim Source As String
    Dim StrFile As String

    'do not forget last backslash in source directory.
    Source = "E:\Planning\03\"
    StrFile = Dir(Source)

    Do While Len(StrFile) > 0                        
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=Source & StrFile
        StrFile = Dir()
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code:

```
Sub opendfiles()

Dim myfile As Variant
Dim counter As Integer
Dim path As String

myfolder = "D:\temp\"
ChDir myfolder
myfile = Application.GetOpenFilename(, , , , True)
counter = 1
If IsNumeric(myfile) = True Then
    MsgBox "No files selected"
End If
While counter <= UBound(myfile)
    path = myfile(counter)
    Workbooks.Open path
    counter = counter + 1
Wend

End Sub
```