# How to count number of rows and to move files automatically with VBA macros?

Tags: vba, excel

My goal is to write a VBA macros that will allow:

1. to choose a folder with files to open
2. then to count number of rows in each file (each file contain only 1 sheet).
3. to move to another folder all the files that contain more than 1 row

I'm very new in VBA, so what i found is how to count number of rows from active worksheet, but i still can't manage automatically files opening and moving to another folder:

```
Sub RowCount()
    Dim iAreaCount As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    iAreaCount = Selection.Areas.Count
    If iAreaCount <= 1 Then
        MsgBox "The selection contains " & Selection.Rows.Count & " rows."
    Else
        For i = 1 To iAreaCount
            MsgBox "Area " & i & " of the selection contains " & _
            Selection.Areas(i).Rows.Count & " rows."
        Next i
    End If
End Sub
```

Could someone help with this, please?

Comment: And our goal is to ***help*** you out with that. :) Do you have a code that you've tried ***and*** tested?

Comment: I will update a question :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually easy. ***Really*** easy. :)

First, code to choose a folder to look into for Excel files. Used Google and searched for `excel vba select folder dialog`. [First result](https://www.google.com.ph/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCgQFjAA&url=http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/294728-browse-folder-visual-basic-applications.html&ei=_jECU5r4JoOplQW-rYDoAg&usg=AFQjCNH866BjYBVvP4x8CVmjzX8J-21SOQ&sig2=Cx0RVoNIkVOvx6aO-0oIzg&bvm=bv.61535280,d.dGI) yields this code:

```
Function GetFolder(strPath As String) As String
Dim fldr As FileDialog
Dim sItem As String
Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With fldr
    .Title = "Select a Folder"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .InitialFileName = strPath
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
End With
NextCode:
GetFolder = sItem
Set fldr = Nothing
End Function
```

We'll get to using it for later. Next, we need a loop to count how many rows there are in each file/sheet. However, we can't count them without these files open. So, let's look for a code that opens workbooks in a loop. Googling `excel vba open excel files in folder`, [we get the second result](https://www.google.com.ph/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDEQFjAB&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11152870/macro-open-all-files-in-a-folder&ei=GDICU5nHK82pkAWTn4CABw&usg=AFQjCNFw369LGmlRxRgKn7F6FfLnpsG8-g&sig2=mI5ck6R0AgGT8kjqI3B-vg&bvm=bv.61535280,d.dGI). First result is a deprecated method in Excel 2007 and up. I will be assuming you're running 2007 and up. Here's the code, applying the proper correction detailed by Siddharth Rout.

```
Sub OpenFiles()
Dim MyFolder As String
Dim MyFile As String
MyFolder = "Blah blah blah"
MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\*.xlsx")
Do While MyFile <> ""
Workbooks.Open Filename:=MyFolder & "\" & MyFile
MyFile = Dir
Loop
End Sub
```

Now, some semi-advanced best practices. Rather than opening each workbook/worksheet/file and counting the rows in each of the opened files (which is highly counter-intuitive), let's modify the above code to count the rows in each file as well, then move them to another folder if they have more than one (1) ***used*** row. We'll also change the above code to take into consideration as well the first function to get the folder we want to apply the second code to.

```
Sub OpenFiles()
Dim MyFolder As String
Dim MyFile As String
MyFolder = GetFolder("C:\users\yourname\Desktop" 'Modify as needed.
MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\*.xlsx") 'Modify as needed.
Do While MyFile <> ""
Workbooks.Open Filename:=MyFolder & "\" & MyFile
MyFile = Dir
Loop
End Sub
```

See what happened there? We called the `GetFolder` function and assigned it to `MyFolder`. We then concatenate `MyFolder` and a wildcarded string, then pass it to `Dir` so we can loop over the files. What's the remaining two things? Right, count the used rows **AND** moving the files. For the used rows, I'll hack a simple function to check the workbook's only sheet to see if the row is 2 or greater.

```
Function CountUsedRows(Wbk As Workbook) As Long
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Set WS = Wbk.Sheets(1)
    CountUsedRows = WS.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'Modify as necessary.
End Function
```

Now that's simple enough. Next, let's write a simple code to move the files. For personal purposes, I'll write a code to *copy* instead. It'll be up to you to modify it for moving, as that's a rather sensitive operation and if it messes up... well. Hmm. But something here tells me that there's a much better option. Copying can cause all manners of error from permission denial to erroneous copying. Since we've got the file open, why not just ***save*** them instead to the new folder?

Now, let's tie them all together neatly.

```
Sub OpenFiles()
    Dim MyFolder As String
    Dim MyFile As String
    Dim TargetWB As Workbook
    MyFolder = GetFolder("C:\Users\yourname\Desktop") 'Modify as needed.
    MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\*.xlsx") 'Modify as needed.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Do While MyFile <> ""
        Set TargetWB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=MyFolder & "\" & MyFile)
        With TargetWB
            If CountUsedRows(TargetWB) > 1 Then
                .SaveAs "C:\Users\yourname\Desktop\Blah\CopyOf" & MyFile 'Modify as needed.
            End If
            .Close
        End With
    MyFile = Dir
    Loop
    Shell "explorer.exe C:\Users\yourname\Desktop\Blah", vbMaximizedFocus 'Open the folder.
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Function GetFolder(strPath As String) As String
    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    Dim sItem As String
    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With fldr
        .Title = "Select a Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = strPath
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
    NextCode:
    GetFolder = sItem
    Set fldr = Nothing
End Function

Function CountUsedRows(Wbk As Workbook) As Long
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Set WS = Wbk.Sheets(1)
    CountUsedRows = WS.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'Modify as necessary.
End Function
```

***Tried and tested.*** Let us know if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is a really great explanation!!! :) I tested, all works. Sorry if i'm totally new in VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Nice answer from Manhattan: that's exactly how I use Excel's built-in functionality to select a folder and fetch a set of file names.

However, there's an interesting side-question in there:

**Are those single-sheet Excel files workbooks, of just .csv text files?**

If they have a .csv extension, you don't need to open them in Excel to count the rows!

Here's the code to do it:

### Fast VBA for Counting Rows in a CSV file

```
 
Public Function FileRowCount(FilePath As String, Optional RowDelimiter As String = vbCr) As Long
' Returns the row count of a text file, including the header row
' Returns - 1 on error

' Unicode-compliant, works on UTF-8, UTF-16, ASCII, with or without a Byte order Marker.
' Reads a typical 30Mb file over the network in 200-300ms. Hint: always copy to a local folder.

' If you're scanning files for use with a SQL driver, use basSQL.TableRowCount: it's 20x slower,
' but it returns a proper test of the file's usability as a SQL 'table'

' Nigel Heffernan    Excellerando.Blogspot.com  2015

' Unit test:
' s=Timer : for i = 0 to 99 : n=FileRowCount("C:\Temp\MyFile.csv") : Next i : Print Format(n,"#,##0") & " rows in " & FORMAT((Timer-s)/i,"0.000") & " sec"

' Network performance on a good day: reads ~ 150 MB/second, plus an overhead of 70 ms for each file
' Local-drive performance:                 ~ 4.5 GB/second, plus an overhead of  4 ms for each file

On Error Resume Next

Dim hndFile     As Long
Dim lngRowCount As Long
Dim lngOffset   As Long
Dim lngFileLen  As Long

Const CHUNK_SIZE As Long = 8192

Dim strChunk As String * CHUNK_SIZE

If Len(Dir(FilePath, vbNormal)) < 1 Then
    FileRowCount = -1
    Exit Function
End If

' trap the error of a folder path without a filename:
If FileName(FilePath) = "" Then
    FileRowCount = -1
    Exit Function
End If

 
    hndFile = FreeFile
    Open FilePath For Binary Access Read Shared As #hndFile


    lngFileLen = LOF(hndFile)


    lngOffset = 1
    Do Until EOF(hndFile)
        Get #hndFile, , strChunk
        FileRowCount = FileRowCount + UBound(Split(strChunk, RowDelimiter))
    Loop


    Close #hndFile
    Erase arrBytes

End Function



Public Function FileName(Path As String) As String
' Strip the folder and path from a file's path string, leaving only the file name

' This does not check for the existence or accessibility of the file:
' all we're doing here is string-handling

' Nigel Heffernan    Excellerando.Blogspot.com  2011

Dim strPath   As String
Dim arrPath() As String

Const BACKSLASH As String * 1 = "\"

strPath = Trim(Path)

If strPath = "" Then Exit Function
If Right$(strPath, 1) = BACKSLASH Then Exit Function

arrPath = Split(strPath, BACKSLASH)

If UBound(arrPath) = 0 Then          ' does not contain "\"
    FileName = Path
Else
    FileName = arrPath(UBound(arrPath))
End If

Erase arrPath

End Function
```

Note the use of the `Split` function to count the row separators: VBA's string-handling is generally slow, especially when you concatenate strings, but there are a couple of places where VBA can perform a string manipulation without internal allocation and deallocation; if you know where they are, you'll find that *parts* of your code run as fast as a 'C' developer's best work.

**Warning: Horrible Hack**
Strictly speaking, I should declare `Dim arrBytes(CHUNK_SIZE) As Byte` and use this Byte array instead of `strChunk` to receive the `Get` from a file opened for binary read.

There are two reasons for not doing it the 'right' way:

1. The last `Get`, which will set end-of-file TRUE, will extract less data from the file than the full 'chunk'. What happens next is that these last few bytes of the file are written into the array *without clearing out the data from the previous 'Get'*. So you have to do additional plumbing, counting bytes off against `LOF(#hwndFile)` to detect the 'Last Get' and branching into a statement that clears the buffer, or allocates a smaller byte array and uses that instead;
2. The code will only cope with UTF-8 2-byte encoded character sets, or with single-byte encoded ASCII 'Latin' text if you do a bit of byte-array substitution around your row delimiters.

The VBA `String` type is a byte array with a wrapper that allows your code (or rather, the compiler) to handle all that complexity in the background.

However, it's much faster to go back into the primordial C, using old-school `Get` statements, than using later libraries like `Scripting.FileSystemObject`. Also, you have some ability to examine the incoming data at the byte level, to debug issues where you're getting '???????' characters instead of the text you were expecting.

Anyway: this is late to the game, as StackOverflow answers go, and it's an answer to the less-interesting part of your question. But it's going to be interesting to people who need a quick rowcount in their data files, and your question comes at the top of the list when they search for that.