# Add one column on all files inside folder in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have 250 different excel files inside a folder (with same layout) with columns `A` to `F`. I need to add a new column on column `G`. The conventional approach would be opening each file and adding new column at `G`. Is there any simple process using Excel macro or any other tools to get this done?

Comment: Yes, you can do this using a macro.  See under "Related" down on the right of this page for similar questions which should give you a start.

Comment: http://www.xlorate.com/vba-examples.html#Loop%20Through%20Folder

Answer (score 3):

[This link](http://www.xlorate.com/vba-examples.html#Loop%20Through%20Folder) helped me. Following is my solution, which works:

```
Sub LoopThroughFolder()

Dim MyFile As String, Str As String, MyDir As String, Wb As Workbook
Dim Rws As Long, Rng As Range
Set Wb = ThisWorkbook
'change the address to suite
MyDir = "C:\Users\dell\Desktop\Folder1\" 'Your Directory
MyFile = Dir(MyDir & "*.xlsx")    'Your excel file extension
ChDir MyDir
Application.ScreenUpdating = 0
Application.DisplayAlerts = 0

Do While MyFile <> ""
    Workbooks.Open (MyFile)
        Range("G1").Value = "NewColumn" 'New Column Name
        ActiveWorkbook.Save
        ActiveWorkbook.Close True
    MyFile = Dir()
Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes here's the code for open all excel files in a folder: [macro - open all files in a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11152870/macro-open-all-files-in-a-folder)

In that loop you can add a new Column to that files