# Import sheet from one excel file to another without specifying destination

Tags: excel, vba

In need of importing an Excel Workbook to the sheets of existing Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook

Have been successful in importing it using the code which the destination is specified I used ".xlsx" as the destination since "*" is used to specify all xlsx file found in the folder.

```
Sub CopySheets()

    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim SourceWB As Workbook
    Dim WS As Worksheet    
    Dim ASheet As Worksheet

    'Turns off screenupdating and events:    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False   
Application.EnableEvents = False

'Sets the variables:
Set WB = ActiveWorkbook
Set ASheet = ActiveSheet
Set SourceWB = Workbooks.Open(WB.Path & "\*.xlsx")  'Modify to match

'Copies each sheet of the SourceWB to the end of original wb:
For Each WS In SourceWB.Worksheets
    WS.Copy after:=WB.Sheets(WB.Sheets.Count)
Next WS        
    SourceWB.Close savechanges:=False
    Set WS = Nothing
    Set SourceWB = Nothing       
WB.Activate
ASheet.Select
    Set ASheet = Nothing
    Set WB = Nothing        
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

The error is "Run-time error '1004': Sorry, we couldn't find C:\Users\ZMOLD01\Desktop\CaseStudy Results*.xlsx. Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?

Comment: Use the `Dir` function. You can't use a wildcard like that in `Workbooks.Open`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11152870/macro-open-all-files-in-a-folder) for how to do it.

Comment: The one you send just opens the file itself not import it into the current excel sheet.

Answer (score 0):

`Dir` gives you the file name if it is found in the Destination.

**Change:**

```
Set SourceWB = Workbooks.Open(WB.Path & "\*.xlsx")
```

**To:**

```
If Len(Dir(wb.path & "\*.xlsx")) > 0 Then

    Set SourceWB = Workbooks.Open(wb.path & "\" & Dir(wb.path & "\*.xlsx"))

Else: Msgbox "File Not Found"
End if
```

Comment: it has an error of "Object variable or With block variable not set" in the line "For Each WS In SourceWB.Worksheets"

Comment: Did msgbox came up ?

Comment: yes it came up and nothing have been copied to my current file

Comment: Then it couldn't find the File. That's Why msgbox came up. Are you sure file is in Format `Results*.xlsx` ? and in the same folder as current workbook ?

Comment: in the location of the excel file im currently using there are only 1 .xlsx file and I need that to be automatically detected so it would be copied in my excel file im using

Comment: Isnt there any pattern of that file name ? what is the name of that file

Comment: sometimes there are 2 files in here. that is why i am figuring out how vba can automatically open without specifying the location or file name

Comment: But there has to be a pattern of the File Name. Otherwise how will VBA identify the file ?

Comment: I have read something that in order to open all the file with .xlsx there is a need of "*"

Comment: Maybe you can benefit from reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31414106/get-list-of-excel-files-in-a-folder-using-vba). If you cannot find a pattern, you need to loop through all the files. that is rather a big code. All the Best